# what are some good strategies for updating docker service images or dockerfile base images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

Some docker images are retagged with the same tag when they are updated.

what sort of strategies or approaches are people working off to ensure they pull newer base images to feed their Dockerfile `FROM` statements or for services that depend on images with upgrades (but the same tag)

I know kubernetes has the *pull_policy* statement, but what is an equivalent soft-option for docker, swarm or docker-compose.

As an example, we use [tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6](https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker/tree/master/python3.6) as a base for Flask apps. 
From time to time, this image is upgraded, and as such the base OS, python, nginx, flask and other dependencies all receive updates, but we always use the same image tag.

docker-compose [does not have](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3574)  a built-in method to handle refreshing base images during build and so we just do the following in a pre-build script to forcefully pull new images:

```
find codebase -name "Dockerfile" | while read line; do cat $line | awk '/FROM/ {print $2}' | xargs docker pull
```

This is OK, but we have no real way of managing this update process.

Is there a better way?

Comment: With Docker-Compose: what is wrong with *container.docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d*? This should pull updated images for mutable image tags and update affected containers. Though, Docker Swarm does what you are looking for out of the box: whenever a swarm service is scheduled, the image:tag is pulled from the image registry.

Comment: Because it doesn't pull images that we build off.   A few applications push the source around and we use the build: context: options of docker-compose.  if From: image:fixed-tag has been updated, we've no automatic way of tracking this and pull only deals with referenced images, not builds. Thx

Comment: I missed that its about updating base images pointing to a mutable tag.  It seems there is no way to do this with implicit docker-compose builds. Though, an explicit build should get you there: `docker-compose build --pull`.

Comment: @Metin you're right.  I don't know why i've missed this.  The introduction of this pre-dates the issue linked above.  As we've seen there are couple of different scenarios for pulling images or base images and this one wasn't discussed there.  
Please answer and i'll mark it :)
https://github.com/docker/compose/commit/39786d4da7127bb1a0898da8c63ad77ec0adf8a3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker compose will use the current image from the local image cache for the base image, unless the build is trigger explicitly using `docker-compose build --pull`.

If you one day should decide to seperate the build and run lifecycle, `docker build --pull` provides the same behavior.